# Question regarding using substring and not having to subtract 1

Tags: java, substring

Create a program that prints the first part of a word. The program asks the user for the word and the length of the first part. Use the substring method in your program. https://puu.sh/EqqmC/231457edec.png

The code below provides the correct answer, but I wanted to know why it is not necessary to subtract 1 from the length in order to produce the word with the correct number of chars.
ie) if String word is "example" and length int is 4, return value is "exam", but if interpreted starting the count from 0, result should be "examp"

return text.substring(0, length);

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstPart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String word = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Length of the first part: ");
        int length = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Result: " + firstPart(word, length));
    }
    // prints the first part of the word
    public static String firstPart(String text, int length) {
       return text.substring(0, length);
    }
}
```

if String word is "example" and length int is 4, return value is "exam"

Comment: The [`String.substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) Javadoc **explicitly** says: *The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.*

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ending index is not included bascily  text.substring(0, length) is from 0 to length-1